# Breeze.js - WebApi 404 Errors using previous version's syntax for ExecuteQuery

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, breeze

In  the previous version of breeze.js (for  MVC4,  EF5 and webapi1),  I would define  EntityManager

```
var em = new breeze.EntityManager('breeze/MyWebApiController');
```

and breeze generated my route to ExecuteQuery("TestMethod") perfectly:
     "breeze/MyWebApiController/TestMethod"

But now in the current version of  breeze.js with MVC5, EF6 and WebApi2, the same ExecuteQuery("TestMethod") to the WebApi controller fails with a 404 because breeze mistakenly generates the route path with the View's subfolder name prefixed to the path like so:

```
"MyViewsFolderName/breeze/MyWebApiController/TestMethod"
```

*The only way I have been able to successfully call a WebApi2 Breeze controller  method is if I specify a dataservice  variable when I create EntityManager like:*

```
var path = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + '/';

var dataServiceTest = new breeze.DataService({
    serviceName: path + 'breeze/MyWebApiController',
hasServerMetadata: false,
});

var em = new breeze.EntityManager({ dataService: dataServiceTest });
```

Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding how to use breeze for WebApi2

Comment: This sounds like a Web API routing issue not a Breeze issue.  Show your routeConfig.cs please.

Comment: Please identify the specific breeze versions you are using (previous and now) and whether you are talking to Web API or Web API OData (which adapter you are using). There have been NO breeze client changes in this area recently ... unless you're talking about Web API OData ... in which case they've broken the protocol every time.